# Pagination with special loading function?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, load, pagination

I was searching for a script or at least a code snippet but haven't really made any progress. Anyway, I'm looking for a script that works like a simple pagination javascript but it should be accessible by linking from anywhere in the document and by calling it with the URL (e.g. on www.abc.de/default.html#thirddiv the third page of the pagination is displayed). Further, the contents should be loaded upon request (when the user clicks on the link and enters the specific page of the pagination), so that cookies, that have been set or deleted in the same document earlier can be used later without reloading the entire page. Something like that is used on Facebook for calling contents and loading them.

I've found a script on CSS Tricks called BetterBlogroll but I don't really get my mind into this. A pagination script from DynamicDrive is already working very well on the page but my problem is that there should be running three of them on the same page and as I said, the content should be loaded upon the user's request.

The script I'd need does not has to be with loads of CSS, the best way would be plain javascript and only the required CSS and HTML data. Anything else just disturbs. If anyone can help me out here, I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ryan Bates's [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) #174 and #175. These two are *not* rails specific, and explain this well.